# How to update the file .env with a form symfony4

Tags: php, mysql, config, symfony4

i would like update the file .env with a form but when i write in the file .env and i test if i can connect, it doesn't work.

thanks.

it's the maincontroller

...

```
$form = $this->createForm(ConfigurationType::class);            
            if($request->isMethod('POST')){                             
                $form->handleRequest($request);             
                if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){                   
                    $data_form = $form->getData();
                    unset($form);               
                    $form = $this->createForm(ConfigurationType::class);                    

                    $new_conf2 = "DATABASE_URL=mysql://".$data_form['username'].":".$data_form['password']."@".$data_form['adresse']."/";
                    $lines = file('../.env');                                   
                    $temp = "";

                    foreach($lines as $line){                       
                        if(strstr($line, "DATABASE_URL")){
                            echo "C'est la bonne.";
                        }else{
                            echo "Non";
                            $temp .= $line;
                        }
                    }

                    $temp2 = $temp;

                    try{                        
                        $nom_bd = "symfony_test";                           
                        $temp2 .= $new_conf2;
                        file_put_contents('../.env');                                                   
                        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                        $em->getConnection()->connect();                            
                        $connected = $em->getConnection()->isConnected();                                           
                        $sql ="CREATE DATABASE ".$nom_db;                           
                        $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);                            
                        $result = $stmt->execute();                             
                        return $this->redirectToRoute('index');                                                                             
                    }catch(\Exception $e){
                        echo "Erreur pas de connexion".$e->getMessage();                            
                    }                   
                }
```

...

Answer (score 0):

If this is your actual code, I think the problem is that you are only providing one argument to file_put_contents(). It requires at least two. The second is the data to be written to the file.

```
                try{                        
                    $nom_bd = "symfony_test";                           
                    $temp2 .= $new_conf2;

                    file_put_contents('../.env', $theDataToBeWritten );// <--

                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                    $em->getConnection()->connect();                            
                    $connected = $em->getConnection()->isConnected();                                           
                    $sql ="CREATE DATABASE ".$nom_db;                           
                    $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);                            
                    $result = $stmt->execute();                             
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('index');                                                                             
                }catch(\Exception $e){
                    echo "Erreur pas de connexion".$e->getMessage();                            
                }
```

Hope that helps.